# Simple gnome panel applet to fetch data periodically over http?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, applet

I'm looking for simple gnome-panel applet that can fetch data (text) from URL and display that on gnome panel. Loading data every 30 seconds.

I would like to use this for display data from personal weather station. 
On http://lanip/weather.php I could output plain text: -14*C, 7.7m/s
And it gets displayed on gnome panel.

Answer (score 3):

I think if it's going to be usable in any future distributions of Ubuntu it would be better if it was a Application indicator

You can check some examples at [DesktopExperienceTeam ApplicationIndicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)

and if you have any problems [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro) one of the users here is one of the Desktop Experience Team. So he should be able to point you in the right direction.

hope this helps

Edit: there is a [Weather-indicator](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator) in Launchpad already and if its not exactly what you are looking for you could give them some feature suggestions or if you are any good at coding you could give them a hand.

Comment: Ok Roland updated with more info for a proper answer

Comment: better now ;) lol

Comment: i doff my cap to you, sir